# How to Display EC2 Instance name using Boto 3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, boto

I am using the below code for displaying instance_id,instance_type but I am unable to display the Instance name which I want

`print (instance.id, instance.instance_type, region)` this is working but this not instance.instance_name

```
import boto3
access_key = "AKIAJ5G2FAUVO3TXXXXXXXX"
secret_key = "nk7eytkWfoSDU0GwvBZVawQvXXXXXX"
client = boto3.client('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region_name='us-east-1')
ec2_regions = [region['RegionName'] for region in client.describe_regions()['Regions']]
for region in ec2_regions:
                conn = boto3.resource('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region_name=region)
                instances = conn.instances.filter()
                for instance in instances:
                    if instance.state["Name"] == "running":
                        print (instance.instance_name,instance.id, instance.instance_type, region)
```

Comment: You can check the boto3 docs or if you can use PDB, just debug it and list the attributes using dir(instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There `instance` object you are using does not have a name attribute. The reason is that the "Name" of an instance, is only **based on a tag** called `Name`. So you have to get tags, and find a tag name of `Name`:

```
def get_tag(tags, key='Name'):

  if not tags: return ''

  for tag in tags:
  
    if tag['Key'] == key:
      return tag['Value']
    
  return ''

ec2_regions = [region['RegionName'] for region in client.describe_regions()['Regions']]

for region in ec2_regions:
    conn = boto3.resource('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region_name=region)
    instances = conn.instances.filter()
    for instance in instances:
        instance_name = get_tag(instance.tags)        
        print (instance_name, instance.id, instance.instance_type, region)
```

Comment: thanks, sir code is working fine but it is showing below error also

Comment: for tag in tags:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: I am a non python guy so please help me here

Comment: @aviraldb I updated the answer. You can check now.

Comment: thank you very very much, sir , have an awesome day ahead

Comment: you saved my life today ,Working on very critical project

Comment: @aviraldb No problem. Glad it worked out:-)